# Ignore a certain webpage when pressing back button

Tags: android, android-webview, back-button

Recently I added a local error page for my Android webview app. So when a certain webpage fails to load properly, it shows that local html file.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {      

        //On error, open local file
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/myerrorpage.html");

        }

});
```

My code when the back button is pressed:

```
private Boolean exit = false;
private long timeStamp = 0;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
@Override
// Detect when the back button is pressed
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    }
    else {
        if (exit) {
            exit = false; //added
            this.finish();
        }
        else {

            //added:
            if (timeStamp == 0 || (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStamp) > 3000) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to close.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                exit = true;

                timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis(); //added

                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        exit = false;
                    }
                }, 3 * 1000);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Specific problem:**

When I press the back button but my previous page was "file:///android_asset/www/myerrorpage.html", it should ignore that errorpage and immediately go back go the last webpage that loaded correctly. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (wvContactUs.canGoBack()) {
            wvContactUs.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }



webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {      

        //On error, open local file
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/myerrorpage.html");
                onBackPressed();
        }

});
```